Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata in springboot, api
Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
How to fix it?

Could you please edit the question to include a simple code sample to demonstrate the exception and your properties file or Hibernate config? Could you also specify the platform that you are using, including whether you are using containers? You could consider using setProperty or doing an nvm clean.
